# Nivo slider: Click first slide to start

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

Nivo Slider for jQuery:
I'm sure I'm missing something, but is there a way to have the slider start and loop by clicking on the first image?
I have a series of 8 images that I'm replacing an SWF with, but the first slide says "Click to start". I know I can turn on the manual option, but that's not what I need. I just need the slider to start it's loop when the first image is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to set the `manualAdvance: true` - look at the [complete list of options](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/) here.

And then just attach a `click` event listener to the slideshow/first slide and set the `manualAdvance` back to `false`, so it can continue to play

Comment: I get the idea of the event listener, but how do you change the manualAdvance?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put the following in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
   $('#Slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
   $('#Slider').live('click', function() {$('#Slider').data('nivoslider').start();});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the slider wouldn't stop. The console showed that it ran, but it just didn't stop. I ended up creating a loop and that seems to do the job but thanks very much.

Comment: Nice. Do you have an URL, I would be interested! Thanks Steph

Comment: If you e-mail me, I can send you the URL.